# Can't read files from BlobStore

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, blobstore

I have been trying to write and read files directly from the BlobStore, but it just doesnt work. 
The issue is I open the file like `file = fileService.getBlobFile(blobKey);` and it doesn't throw any exception but right in the next line I call `readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, false);` and that one throws a FileNotFoundException.

I'm confused as to why the first line did not throw the exception.

[Here is the same issue](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/85a39d18de1c222d#)

Unfortunately no one answered that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had any problems with writes or deletes, but I too get a `FileNotFoundException` when using `openReadChannel(...)` with an `AppEngineFile`.

I've tried using an `AppEngineFile` created from its constructor taking a complete path.  I've tried using an `AppEngineFile` obtained from `getBlobFile(...)` like you do above.  Either way, when the `AppEngineFile` is passed to `openReadChannel(...)` a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

My workaround was to let `BlobstoreService.serve(...)` do all the work of reading and sending the file.  I suspect that using the `FileService` to read from an `AppEngineFile` isn't supported yet (I'm using 1.6.0), so reads must be done via the `BlobstoreService` (`serve(...)`, `fetchData(...)`, `BlobstoreInputStream`).

Comment: I think this works in the way Blob store was meant to be used. We used to store large data files that we needed to process so I really needed to process the file. If all you need is serve the file probably this is the right way to do it. We ended up dropping the google app thing completely for this project but it would have been nice to know why the above code did not work. Thanks anyway.